# Fresh install Ubuntu 14.04.03 boots every second time

Tags: lvm, lts

Fresh install. One boot is blank purple screen, second boot - normal, third - blank purple, forth - normal and so on. Can this be fixed?

I use entire disk encrytption LVM

Comment: when I install from the same usb without full disk encryption - it boots normaly each time

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, same configuration, but my screen goes blank instead of purple.

When that happens, if I press escape, I can see that it's prompting me for the drive encryption password, so the display isn't initialising properly for some reason.

To work around it, I edited `/etc/default/grub` and changed the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

To this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`

It now boots in text mode, asks for my encryption password, then proceeds via the normal GUI.

Comment: Thank tou for the answer, but I already installed Ubuntu 15, so someone else will try this.

Comment: i try this with no luck